# Migrating from Amazon S3 to Azure Storage (Django web app)

Tags: python, django, azure, amazon-s3, boto

I maintain this Django web app where users congregate and chat with one another. They can post pictures too if they want. I process these photos (i.e. optimize their size) and store them on an Amazon S3 bucket (like a 'container' in Azure Storage). To do that, I set up the bucket on Amazon, and included the following configuration code in my **settings.py**:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_S3_FORCE_HTTP_URL = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('awssecretkey')
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('awsaccesskeyid')
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT='boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'dakadak.in'
```

Additionally `Boto 2.38.0` and `django-storages 1.1.8` are installed in my virtual environment. **Boto** is a Python package that provides interfaces to Amazon Web Services, whereas **django-storages** is a collection of custom storage backends for Django.

I now want to stop using Amazon S3 and instead migrate to **Azure Storage**. I.e. I need to migrate all existing files from S3 to Azure Storage, and next I need to configure my Django app to save all new static assets on Azure Storage.

I can't find precise documentation on what I'm trying to achieve. Though I do know **django-storages** [support Azure](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/azure.html). Has anyone done this kind of a migration before, and can point out where I need to begin, what steps to follow to get everything up and running?

*Note: Ask me for more information if you need it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my experience, you can do the two steps for migrating from Amazon S3 to Azure Storage for Django web app.

The first step is moving all files from S3 to Azure Blob Storage. There are two ways you can try.

1. Using the tools for S3 and Azure Storage to move files from S3 to local directory to Azure Blob Storage.

These tools below for S3 can help moving files to local directory.

- AWS Command Line(https://aws.amazon.com/cli/): `aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET/FOLDER localfolder --recursive`
- S3cmd    Tools(http://s3tools.org/): `s3cmd -r sync s3://BUCKET/FOLDER localfolder`
- S3 Browser (http://s3browser.com/) :
  This is a GUI client.

For moving local files to Azure Blob Storage, you can use AzCopy Command-Line Utility for high-performance uploading, downloading, and copying data to and from Microsoft Azure Blob, File, and Table storage, please refer to the document https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/.

Example: `AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer`

2. Migrating by programming with Amazon S3 and Azure Blob Storage APIs in your familiar language like Python, Java, etc. Please refer to their API usage docs https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/ and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html.

The second step is following the document http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/azure.html to re-configure Django `settings.py` file. Django-storages would allow any uploads you do to be automatically stored in your storage container.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE='storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'
AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME='myaccount'
AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY='account_key'
AZURE_CONTAINER='mycontainer'
```

You can find these settings on Azure Portal as @neolursa said.

---

**Edit**:
On Azure old portal:
[image]

On Azure new portal:
[image]

Comment: @HassanBaig On Azure old portal, you can find it thru click the `MANAGE ACCESS KEYS`at the bottom of `Storage -> <Your Storage>`. On Azure new portal, you can find it thru `<Your Storage> Storage account (classic) -> All settings -> Keys`. If you still can't find it, please feel free to let me know. I will show the screenshot to you.

Comment: @HassanBaig I think that `Azure Container` you said is the container of Blob Storage. Yes, you can create the blob containers as any name that must follow the container naming rules. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/#create-a-container to pay attention to the `IMPORTANT` notice.

Comment: @HassanBaig As I known, there is no property to do that because of the endpoint is based on https protocol. If you use http url, it will be force rewrited as https url. So if you have any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I have an app live on internet.org's platform. Hitherto, Facebook had forbidden its developers from using https protocol, but I will ask their tech support team again. I want to be able to use Azure Storage instead of S3 for this. Let's see.

Comment: Have a follow up question about Azure Cloud config. I figured it start a separate SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266346/azure-cloud-storage-config-error-in-django-app-could-not-load-azure-bindings

Comment: @HassanBaig OK, I will follow the new one.

Answer (score 1):

The link you've shared has the configuration for Django to Azure Blobs. Now when I did this all I had to do is to go to the Azure portal. Under the storage account, get the access keys as below. Then create a container and give the container name to Django configuration. This should be enough. However I've done this a while ago.

For the second part, migrating the current files from S3 bucket to BLOB, there a couple of tools you can use;

If you are using visual studio, you can find the blobs under the Server Explorer after entering your azure account credentials in Visual Studio.

Alternatively you can use third party tools like [Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) or [Cloudberry explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx).

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: I'm going to try this. No chance you can share any snippet from your `settings.py`? Secondly, would I not need something like **boto** here?

Comment: I'll see if I can find the project file. In the meantime there are two links. First one is how to use Azure Storage with Python specifically on MS Azure documentation. Second one is a sample Django code that is already connected to Azure Storage.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-azure-storage

Comment: Hey neolursa: I made some progress on this front, but am now stuck at this error:'module' object has no attribute 'WindowsAzureMissingResourceError' Details here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267927/exception-while-setting-up-azure-cloud-storage-for-django-app-module-object-h