# Azure Cloud Storage config error in Django app: Could not load Azure bindings

Tags: python, django, azure

I'm trying to set up Azure Cloud Storage for my Django app (app hosted on Azure VM with Ubuntu OS). I have Django-storages installed as a package, and I've followed this: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/azure.html, adding the following lines to my **settings.py** file:

```
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'
    AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'photodatabasestorage'
    AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'something'
    AZURE_CONTAINER = 'somecontainer'
```

Prior to this, I was using similar settings to store images via Amazon S3 (and everything worked perfectly for 2 weeks). The moment I replaced the S3 code with the Azure code, I started getting the following error:

Exception Value:

```
**Could not load Azure bindings.** See
https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python

Exception Location:
    /home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/azure_storage.py
in <module>, line 12?
```

And here's the code snippet in question:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
try:
    import azure
    import azure.storage
except ImportError:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
        "Could not load Azure bindings. "
        "See https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't installed the Python bindings for azure yet. You can install them with:

```
pip install azure
```

Installation docs are [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/python-how-to-install/).

Comment: Yea it's purely an inability to `import`. BTW django-storages requires adding 'storages' to INSTALLED_APPS as well. I've never done that, yet it's been working fine for me. Should I add that to INSTALLED_APPS too?

Comment: Oh you didn't have context. I meant I'm using django-storages as a storage backend here. Their docs need me to add `strorages` to INSTALLED_APPS, though I've never done that hitherto (and with AWS, it's been working fine). Should I also include `storages` in INSTALLED_APPS, in your opinion?

Comment: Okay problem solved, new one emerged, so accepting this and opening a separate SO post. Thanks Alasdair!

Comment: It's always a good idea to follow the docs, so yes, I would add `'storages'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Why would it work without being added to INSTALLED_APPS? I've never really been able to get clarity on that one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django-Storages so I can't say. Maybe it's required for a use case that you haven't hit yet, or maybe the docs are wrong and it's not necessary to add it.