# python script to Transfer file from Amazon AWS s3 to Azure Blob using SAS Token

Tags: python-3.x, azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a file from Amazon S3 bucket to Azure Blob Storage using SAS token, I need to write a python code for that, I am trying to check in google and always finding the generating sas token related code, but my client is providing the SAS token, I don't need to create any SAS token, just use the existing one.

could somebody help me who knows python.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written so far and the issues you’re running into.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround if you already have a SAS token is to use `azcopy` from Powershell. Below is the command that you can use

```
azcopy cp "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/" "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer<SAS>" --recursive
```

Also try refering [Migrating from Amazon S3 to Azure Storage (Django web app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173861/migrating-from-amazon-s3-to-azure-storage-django-web-app)

**REFERENCES:**
[Move your data from AWS S3 to Azure Storage using AzCopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/move-your-data-from-aws-s3-to-azure-storage-using-azcopy/)